# What is the recommended way to simulate concepts and constraints?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

Before the introduction of concepts and constraints, there are several ways to simulate this compile-time check. Take a "`order()`" function for example: (how to implement `LessThanComparable` without concepts or constraints is another story)

- Use `static_assert`

  ```
  template <typename T, typename U>
  void order(T& a, U& b)
  {
      static_assert(LessThanComparable<U,T>, "oh this is not epic");
      if (b < a)
      {
          using std::swap;
          swap(a, b);
      }
  }
  ```

  This approach won't work for function overloading.
- Use `typename = enable_if`

  ```
  template <typename T, typename U,
      typename = std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>>>>
  void order(T& a, U& b)
  {
      if (b < a)
      {
          using std::swap;
          swap(a, b);
      }
  }
  ```

  What if an over-"intelligent" guy specifies a third parameter by hand?
- Use `enable_if` in the function prototype:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename U>
  std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>>, void> order(T& a, U& b)
  {
      if (b < a)
      {
          using std::swap;
          swap(a, b);
      }
  }
  ```

  Sometimes also doesn't work in function overloading.
- Use `enable_if` as the type of a dummy non-type template parameter

  ```
  template <typename T, typename U,
      std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>>, void*> = nullptr> // or int = 0
  void order(T& a, U& b)
  {
      if (b < a)
      {
          using std::swap;
          swap(a, b);
      }
  }
  ```

  I saw this before, and I can't think of any drawbacks.
- And many other variants.

Which ones are preferable or recommended? What is the benefits and drawbacks?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The usual way is using _type traits_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean the usual way to implement the `LessThanComparable`?

Comment: No I mean in general. Type traits are used to verify concepts and constraints of template parameters.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, they are very useful in metaprogramming 

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181702/which-type-traits-cannot-be-implemented-without-compiler-hooks

Comment: There is a slight drawback to non-type template parameter approach. If you wish to separate definition from declaration (e.g. for a template member function) you'll have to duplicate the "constraint".

Comment: Related to [why-should-i-avoid-stdenable-if-in-function-signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600201/why-should-i-avoid-stdenable-if-in-function-signatures) with one drawback listed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532681/2684539) for the preferred approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a complicated topic and is not easy give an answer at your question.

Anyway, some observations/suggestions, without any pretense to being exhaustive.

(1) the `static_assert()` way

```
static_assert(LessThanComparable<U,T>, "oh this is not epic");
```

is a good solution if you want a function that works only with some types and give an error (a clear error, because you can choose the error message) if called with wrong types.

But usually is the wrong solution when you want an alternative. Isn't a SFINAE solution. So calling the function with arguments of wrong types gives an error and doesn't permit that another function is used in substitution.

(2) You're right about the

```
typename = std::enable_if_t</* some test */>>
```

solution. An user can explicit a third parameter by hand. Joking, I say that this solution can be "hijacked".

But isn't the only drawback of this solution.

Suppose you have two complementary `foo()` functions that have to be enabled/disabled via SFINAE; the first one when a test is true, the second one when the same test if false.

You can think that the following solution is dangerous (can be hijacked) but can work

```
/* true case */
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<true == some_test_v<T>>>
void foo (T t)
 { /* something with t */ }

/* false case */
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<false == some_test_v<T>>>
void foo (T t)
 { /* something with t */ }
```

Wrong: this solution simply doesn't works because you're enabling/disabling not the second typename but only the default value for the second typename. So you're not completely enabling/disabling the functions and the compiler have to consider two functions with the same signature (the signature of a function doesn't depends from default values); so you have a collision and obtain an error.

The following solutions, SFINAE over the returned type

```
std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>, void> order(T& a, U& b)
```

(also without `void`, that is the default type

```
std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>> order(T& a, U& b)
```

) or over the second type (following the Yakk's suggestion about a not-standard allowed `void *`)

```
template <typename T, typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>>, bool> = true>
```

are (IMHO) good solutions because both of they avoid the hijacking risk and are compatible with two complementary functions with the same name and signature.

I suggest a third possible solution (no hijack-able, complementary compatible) that is the addition of a third defaulted value with SFINAE enabled/disabled type: something as

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void order(T& a, U& b, std::enable_if_t<LessThanComparable<U,T>> * = nullptr)
```

Another possible solution avoid at all SFINAE but use tag-dispatching; something as

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void order_helper (T & a, U & b, std::true_type const &)
 { if (b < a) { std::swap(a, b); } }

// something different if LessThanComparable is false ?
template <typename T, typename U>
void order_helper (T & a, U & b, std::false_type const &)
 { /* ???? */ }

template <typename T, typename U>
void order (T & a, U & b)
 { order_helper(a, b, LessThanComparable<U,T>{}); }
```

This in case `LessThanComplarable` inherit from `std::true_type` when the condition is true, from `std::false_type` when the condition is false.

Otherwise, if `LessThanComparable` gives only a boolean value, the call to `order_helper()` can be

```
order_helper(a, b, std::integral_constant<bool, LessThanComparable<U,T>>{});
```

(3) if you can use C++17, there is the `if constexpr` way that can avoid a lot of overloading

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void order(T& a, U& b)
{
   if constexpr ( LessThanComparable<U, T> )
    { 
      if ( b < a )
         std::swap(a, b);
    }
   else
    {
      // what else ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look how `range-v3` library emulates concepts https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/range_concepts.hpp

There is also a way to use template aliases to achieve something similar to concepts [Using alias templates for sfinae: does the language allow it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048938/using-alias-templates-for-sfinae-does-the-language-allow-it)

And, you have missed `decltype` variants on your list:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto order(T& a, U& b) -> decltype(void(b < a))
{
    if (b < a)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a, b);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename U,
    typename = decltype(void(b < a))>
void order(T& a, U& b)
{
    if (b < a)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: `decltype` is mostly the way to write the traits. In the similar way `std::void_t` would allow SFINAE on type instead of boolean, but doesn't really change the OP's variants.

Comment: I think `decltype` better belongs to the implementation of those concept-simulators like `LessThanComparable`. Also a variant, though.

Answer (score 2):

Non-type template parameters of type `void*` are not allowed in at least some versions of the standard; I'd use `bool` with value `=true`.

Otherwise, use that.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you cannot use `void*` as a non-type template parameter.

Comment: Anyway, [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) seems to suggest that a pointer to object or function is allowed as a non-type template parameter in every standard from before C++11 to C++20. **Is `void*` considered a "pointer to object"?**

Comment: @l.f. I'd ask a language lawyer tagged question here, or read the standard; my concern is that I have experienced otherwise reasonable compilers refusing void ptr arguments, which are easy to avoid, so I just avoid them.